# Initial value not showing up in DecimalField

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a `DecimalField` and I have set the initial value like so:

```
class RawProductForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="")
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
    price = forms.DecimalField(initial=199.99)
```

Here is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
from .models import Product

def product_create_view(request):
    form = RawProductForm(request.GET)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RawProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            Product.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

However, the initial value is not showing up when I render the page:

[image: screenshot]

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you share the view where you use this form?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `request.GET` here as a source of data, since then it will try to parse the data out of a (likely non-existing) querystring. If you want to create an empty non-bounded form, you construct it *without* data:

```
def product_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RawProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            Product.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RawProductForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

That being said, your code has some additional problems. If the creation is successful with a POST request, it is better to redirect, and implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Furthermore you probably here should use a [**`ModelForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), this will ensure that the creation of the model object (here a `Product`) is done correctly.